# Unable to create the selected preference page. (Eclipse error)

Tags: eclipse, pydev

[image]

I recently tried to configure Eclipse for Python use and I got this same error after reinstalling PyDev at least 3 times and Eclipse twice. Any solution to this error?
I'm running Java 8.171, and I'm on a Mac running OS X Sierra.

Thank you

Comment: Look in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory to see if there is a more detailed message.

Comment: Yeap, without the error message from the .log it's hard to know what happened... also, please say which pydev version you have and which eclipse version you have.